# Replace multiple values in wordpress postmeta database table with another value

Tags: sql, replace

Hi I am trying to find and replace all instances the value 10.6 in my postmeta tables where the meta key matches my query.

Here is what I have so far

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta`
SET `meta_value` = REPLACE (`meta_value`,'10.6','13.9')
WHERE `meta_key`='vpc-config'
```

I simulated a query and it returned 45 rows.     There are 45 `vpc-config` that do have the value 10.6 in there but there are literally hundreds of values 10.6.  Can anyone help with the correct syntax, here.

The meta_value table cell for these has approc 500k length.

Here is an example of one of the lines within that one cell that need replacing.  I have 45 cells each with about 120 of these values that need changing from 10.6 to 13.9. I can confirm that a regular find/replace on Notepad++ only changes the 10.6 to 13.9 and does not cause any issues. I am just trying to save some time.

```
(018)";s:4:"icon";s:57:"/wp-content/themes/pinkequine/cf/mattesicons/rope/018.png";s:5:"image";s:68:"/wp-content/themes/pinkequine/cf/mattes/euroftpaddr/piping/3/018.png";s:5:"price";s:4:"10.6";}i:26;a:6:{s:9:"option_id";s:20:"option-5aff52bc14300";s:5:"group";s:0:"";s:4:"name";s:11:"Khaki
```

Comment: Do you also want to replace 210.6 with 213.9?

Comment: Some sample data and what you are expecting wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Hi Stu, I have added an example of part of the meta_value, I havent put the whole cell there as its massive. I hope this helps clarify what I am trying to do.